# Camscanner name saving policy

Tags: applications

My exact problem is how to find out the sequence of saving files in the `/sdcard/Camscanner/.images` dirs in batch mode scanning. File names are a 192-bit sequence of alphabets and numbers, like these ones:

1. `WUeQbMPF6d1garTRJMyU6TF3.jpg`
2. `CULJYQf0QJbM5PLJhEJVCKYW.jpg`